# MolecularJS :: Correlation details :: how to pass logged in user to action method

Tags: node.js, moleculer

I am new to molecular Js, can someone please help me in understanding ,how to pass the context of current request in action handlers?

to be more specific, In **authenticate** method of API gateway I am validating token and decoding it. and I need this decoded token object in action handler methods.

I have tried with ctx.meta , but getting null when i try to accessed it action handler.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was just updating the property in **authenticate** method.

ctx.meta.user = myUserObject;

But actually, we should return a Promise with resolution.

return Promise.resolve(myUserObject);

it automatically sets the ctx.meta.user with myUserObject